# INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE each row SQL

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, store

I have the following data in a table TABLE1

```
SessionID
S1
S2
S3
```

i have the following data in another TABLE2

```
EmployeeID | Session
1          | NULL
2          | NULL
3          | NULL
```

What i would like to do is update/Insert each row
example

```
UPDATE table2 SET Session= (SELECT SessionID FROM TABLE1)
INSERT INTO( COPY each row and insert 2nd row session id from table1)
```

The Expected Result:
TABLE2

```
EmployeeID | Session
1          | S1
2          | S1
3          | S1
1          | S2
2          | S2
3          | S2
1          | S3
2          | S3
3          | S3
```

Any insight will help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want a row in TABLE2 for every combination of each row currently in TABLE2 and each row in TABLE1. If so...

```
BEGIN TRAN

SELECT * INTO #temp FROM TABLE2

DELETE TABLE2

INSERT TABLE2
(
    EmployeeID,
    Session
)
SELECT
    temp.EmployeeID,
    TABLE1.SessionID
FROM TABLE1 CROSS JOIN #temp temp

DROP #TEMP

COMMIT TRAN
```

Comment: Hi Daniel ,your way is works. but i face the primary key problem . in the table2 , my employeeid is primary key .so i have tried make session and employee id as candidate key but it fail because my table 2 session is null. any suggestion?

Comment: If `EmployeeID` must be the primary key of `TABLE2` then you simply can't do what you want since it will require duplicate values in that column. If you can remove the current key and replace it with a new composite key covering `EmployeeID` and `Session` then it will work as long as you never have duplicate `Session` values for the same `EmployeeID`. You'll be able to have one NULL value *per* `EmployeeID` but no more than that.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a separate Employee table. To insert data to your EmployeeSession (TABLE2):

```
INSERT INTO EmployeeSession ( EmployeeID, SessionID )
    SELECT Employee.ID, [Session].ID
    FROM Employee, [Session]
```

Comment: thanks but i think daniel's answer is more suitable for my situation

Answer (score 0):

I think the `MERGE` statement helps:

```
MERGE INTO TABLE2 t2
    USING (SELECT t2.EmployeeID, t1.SessionID
FROM TABLE2 t2
CROSS JOIN TABLE1 t1) t
        ON t2.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID AND t2.Session = t.SessionID
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
        INSERT (EmployeeID, Session) VALUES(t.EmployeeID, t.SessionID)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
        DELETE
;
```